# When I run "rake routes", or any rake task, it always loads my environment first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm trying to figure out why my non-environment rake tasks, like:

```
rake routes
```

takes so long to run. It takes over a minute as it loads the complex environment of my application. This is a Rails 2.3.12 application, and my Rakefile is as follows:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/switchtower.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.
require 'thread'
require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))

require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'delayed/tasks'

require 'tasks/rails'
```

Comment: It's just not going to be that fast. Have you tried [rake-sh](https://github.com/jugyo/rake-sh)?

Comment: Also, `rake routes` is not a non-environment task: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/railties/lib/tasks/routes.rake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling `rake routes` does depend on the rails stack and because auf this, the environment is loaded.

what you can do, is use a third party gem like sextant: https://github.com/schneems/sextant/